# How to get data from angular firebase in 2019?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have looked through the entire net... I have applied fireship tutorials and more. I cannot get data from firebase in angular. Please Help.

These are my three methods:

Getting data but its not being called in ngFor HTML.

```
getMessage(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage> {
  this.db.list('messages').valueChanges().subscribe(queriedItems => {
  console.log(queriedItems);

  });
  return this.queriedItems;
}
```

Getting only one msg instead of all saved messages from firebase

```
 returnMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage> {
   this.db.list('messages').valueChanges().subscribe(msg => {
     this.msg = msg;
     this.msgArr.push(msg)
     console.log("test push ", this.msgArr)
   });
   return this.msgArr;
 }
```

And this one gives me an ERROR (please see below)

```
getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage> {
  return this.db.list('messages', ref => {
    return ref.limitToLast(25).orderByKey();
  });
}
```

> FeedComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>       at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4323)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (common.js:4934)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._subscribe (common.js:4924)
>       at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4906)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FeedComponent.html:2)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)

My feed component for calling the getMessage():

```
feed: AngularFireList<ChatMessage>;

constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("feed initializing...")
  this.feed = this.chat.getMessages();
  console.log("Feed ", this.feed);
}

ngOnChanges() {
  this.feed = this.chat.getMessages();
}
```

And this is my HTML

```html
<div class="feed">
  <div *ngFor="let message of feed | async" class="message">
    <app-message [chatMessage]=message></app-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage> {
  return this.db.list('messages', ref => {
    return ref.limitToLast(25).orderByKey();
  });
}
```

Into this:

```
getMessages() {
  return this.db.list('messages', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25)).valueChanges();
}
```

Then change:

```
feed: AngularFireList<ChatMessage>;

constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("feed initializing...")
  this.feed = this.chat.getMessages();
  console.log("Feed ", this.feed);
}
```

Into this:

```
feed;

constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("feed initializing...")
this.chat.getMessages().subscribe(items => {
  console.log(items);
  this.feeds = items 
});
}
```

Change this:

```
<div class="feed">
  <div *ngFor="let message of feed | async" class="message">
    <app-message [chatMessage]=message></app-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let message of feed" class="message">
    <app-message [chatMessage]=message></app-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `async` pipe is used with an observable.

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted

`feeds` is of type AngularFireList which is not an observable.

Therefore add `valueChanges()` which returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array. Then inside the `ngOnInit()` subscribe to that observable and iterate inside the array `feed` in the `ngFor`

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: Peter, it worked! Thanks a bunch for the help. I need to change the sendMsg() a little around for it to work on both ends. Thank you very much for your help.